# Raspberry Pi running Flask locally for iPad

Tags: python, ipad, flask, raspberry-pi

I need to run a flask app on my Raspberry Pi locally. I'm planning on putting it in my car where I will have no internet connection. This doesn't matter as I only need it to run one website that I will write in python using the flask framework.

I have setup a wifi adapter to work as an access point that I can connect to my raspberry pi with.

I'm good with python and flask development, and am very comfortable in a linux style terminal - but I am having trouble finding a way to run a flask app on my Pi that I can access over the Pi's network on an iPad. Do I need to deploy it somehow?

This is how I'm running a network from the Pi: http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/

As of now that allows me to use an iPad to connect to the Pi's network. If I write a small sample app in Flask and run a server from the terminal I can connect to it by entering the Pi's IP address in the iPad's browser. However, when I pull the ethernet plug from the Pi - thus killing it's internet connection) I can no longer load the Flask site on my iPad. I can still connect to the wifi network, but I can't view the flask app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the Raspberry Pi connect to the 'wifi adapter' with the Ethernet cable?

Comment: @dilbert Nope the Raspberry Pi uses a USB WIFI adapter. The Ethernet port is free as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using gunicorn to host flask running on nginx. Details here: [Deploy Flask on Raspberry Pi with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911516/deploy-flask-on-raspberry-pi-with-nginx)