# Deploy Flask on Raspberry Pi with Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app on my raspberry pi using nginx. I've followed these two guides:

http://www.onurguzel.com/how-to-run-flask-applications-with-nginx-using-gunicorn/
http://www.onurguzel.com/managing-gunicorn-processes-with-supervisor/

And have got everything running without error. But when I load a web browser pointing at my PI's IP (I work over ssh) - all I see is the default "welcome to nginx" page. What's going on?

here are my files:

**/home/pi/hello/hello.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/hello.conf** (symlinked to: **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello.itu24.com;

    root /home/pi/hello/hello.py;

    access_log /home/pi/hello/access.log;
    error_log /home/pi/hello/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @gunicorn_proxy;
        }

    location @gunicorn_proxy {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
}
```

Here's my nginx.conf (though I have not changed it at all)

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

---

For the supervisor part:

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/hello.conf**

```
[program:hello]
command = /home/pi/hello/bin/python /home/pi/hello/bin/gunicorn hello:app
directory = /home/pi/hello
user = pi
```

---

I can spin everything up with :

```
sudo supervisorctl start hello
```

But when I hit my Pi's IP:

```
http://192.168.1.28
```

from my macs browser 
all I get is: "Welcome to nginx"

Any ideas? This is my first server that I'm running and deploying to - running it on a Ras Pi probably wasn't the best idea but I'm learning a lot so far.

Comment: what happens when you access http://192.168.1.28:8000? and what about http://192.168.1.28:5000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might running flask on the default port, which is 5000.

Try changing this line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run()
    app.run(port=8000)
```

or change your supervisord command to:

```
command = /home/pi/hello/bin/python /home/pi/hello/bin/gunicorn hello:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I changed my supervisord conf file to the command you specified and I am now able to access the site on my raspberry pi by hitting localhost:8000. It is still not available on my laptop but I'm guessing that's because I'm not using ssh tunneling and I'm only ssh'ed into my Pi on the terminal. Does this sound right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what if you hit 192.168.1.28:8000 and 192.168.1.28 from your machine?

Comment: On my machine, 192.168.1.28 brings up "welcome to nginx" and 192.168.1.28:8000 doesn't work at all.

Comment: @tknickman I believe the other answer, where you remove the symlink default in the sites-enabled folder would fix your problem after restarting the nginx.

Comment: Yes I got it all working now. Thanks! I will mark this as the answer, as this can get it working, but the answer below helps in making the site available at localhost without a port.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make sure the default site is disabled. Simply delete the symlink `default` from `sites-enabled`.

Also, the default port for Flask is 5000 not 8000, so in your `nginx` configuration, you need to change the following:

```
location @gunicorn_proxy {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; # Default port
}
```

Comment: The default is in both the sites-enabled and the sites-available. I will delete it from both places and see what happens.

Comment: You only need to remove the symlink from sites-enabled (these are the sites that are actually active). sites-available holds all configurations; when you create a link from sites-enabled to sites-available _and restart the server_, this will "activate" that particular configuration.